# Flags getting randomly set in RCC(Reset and Clock Control register) on Power On

Tags: embedded, stm32, reset, clock, system-clock

I am working on MM32Spin05 MCU. After power on, all 6 flags in the RCC(Reset and Clock Control) register are getting set.
After a reset, the default value of this register should be 0X XC000000.
But I am observing it as 0X FC000000.
I am not doing anything with respect to the watchdog timers, or the low power module or the s/w reset.

I have a requirement, that, if a software reset is done, a certain page in the flash memory is to be cleared. But on boot up, the flag is set for reasons unknown to me and hence, the flash memory page is getting cleared.
I am actually doing a Power Reset. I am turning off and then turning on the power supply to the MCU. On boot-up, the Software Reset flag is set and hence, according to my code, it is triggering the flash memory page erase. The Flash memory page should be erased ONLY on a software reset, not a power reset. Immediately after the MCU boots up, I print the RCC_CSR Register value, and see that all 6 flags are set.

`LPWRRSTF`: Low power reset flag
`WDGRSTF`: Window watchdog reset flag
`IWDGRSTF`: Independent watchdog reset flag
`SFTRSTF`: Software reset flag
`PORRSTF`: POR/PDR reset flag
`PINRSTF`: PIN reset flag

I am confused, as to why, a power reset is causing the software reset flag to set?

I am stuck on this for more than a week and am fully clueless about it. Any help or suggestions would be highly welcome.
Thanks in Advance

[image: bits in the RCC Register]

Comment: The extra `X` in `0X XC000000` probably means that the bits in that nibble are undefined on reset, or possibly unmodified. What dfoes the documentation say?

Comment: The `X` in `0xXC000000` might mean "don't care" or that the exact value may vary depending on some conditions.

Comment: X in 0xXC000000 does mean Don't Care. The exact value that I am observing is 0xFC000000.

Comment: So then what is your problem? What is your question? If bits are marked as "don't care", perhaps you shouldn't care about their values after reset. Instead if you need to set them to a specific value on power up, you should probably do that at reset as well.

Comment: In case you want to compare the value you can mask out the "don't care" bits, e.g. by using something like `if((RCC_value & 0x0FFFFFFFu) == 0x0C000000u) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: I have a requirement, that, if a software reset is done, a certain page in the flash memory is to be cleared. But on boot up, the flag is set for reasons unknown to me and hence, the flash memory page is getting cleared.

Comment: I am actually doing a Power Reset. I am turning off and then turning on the supply to the MCU. Still, Software Reset flag is set and hence, according to my code, it is triggering the flash memory page erase. 
The Flash memory page should be erased ONLY on a software reset, not a power reset.
Immediately after the MCU boots up, I print the RCC_CSR Register value, and see that all 6 flags are set.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe your requirements instead of using comments to add information. Please show the register values after the different types of reset. Maybe you have to check that `SFTRSTF` is 1 and `PORRSTF` and `PINRSTF` are 0?

Comment: **Please don't use comments to add information. [Edit] your question instead.** What value do you get after a software reset?

Comment: I have never done a software reset. 
I am only doing a power reset. Immediately after boot-up, the software reset flag is also getting set, which is triggering the flash page to erase. Hence, I am wondering, why are all these flags getting set

Comment: @sukhbir1996 Then do a software reset and check the value. Please show (the related part of) your code. As I already wrote: Maybe you have to check that SFTRSTF is 1 and that both PORRSTF and PINRSTF are 0 to detect a software reset, and maybe you have to do something to clear the flags. Citation from the user manual: *`SFTRSTF`: Software reset flag. Set to ’1’ by hardware when a software reset occurs. Cleared by writing to the RMVF bit.*

Comment: As the manual says, the top 4 bits are "don't care" on power-on (or pin) reset, and they can have **any value**. **Only if none of PORRSTF and PINRSTF** are set, the other bits are relevant. Even then you need to read the manual carefully to understand the conditions of these bits. There might be more to do than a simple single-bit check.

Comment: Thank you @thebusybee. What you said, worked like a dream!

Comment: OK, good to know. I wrote an equally answer, you might like to mark it. This will help others with the same issue. (This is how this site is supposed to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the manual says, the top 4 bits are "don't care" on power-on (or pin) reset, and they can have **any value**.

Only if **none of `PORRSTF` and `PINRSTF`** are set, the other bits are relevant.

Even then you need to read the manual carefully to understand the conditions of these bits. There might be more to do than a simple single-bit check.